# Why does this myFunction().then() operation seem to hang indefinitely?

Tags: node.js

I am having some trouble with some NON PRODUCTION code. I want to process about 3000 array elements. If I strace the node process, it is sitting at `epoll_wait(5`,  so presumably I am blocking the main thread.

Can anyone suggest either a) what I am doing wrong or b) how I can look at the execution stack / event loop to examine exactly why the code is hanging? I have attempted to debug and step through the code and have that process working but am none the wiser.

UPDATED code using Promises.map:

```
connection.query(firstPostQuery,{ x: whiteListString }, function( err, rows ) {

    Promise.map(rows, function(result) {


        return sfs.isSpammer({
            ip: result.ip,
            email: result.email,
            username: result.poster
        }).then(function(res) {
console.log(parseInt(res.username.appears) == 1); //evaluates to true

            if (parseInt(res.username.appears) == 1 ) {

                console.log(res.toJSON());
                fs.appendFile(__dirname + '/stopforumspam.txt', res.poster + '\n',
                    function(err) {
                        if (err) {
                            throw err;
                        }
                        return true;
                    });

            } else {
                fs.appendFile(__dirname + '/stopforumspam.txt',
                    'nope\n',
                    function(err) {
                        if (err) {
                            throw err;
                        }
                        return true;
                    });
            }
        });
        //Iteration completed
    }, {concurrency: 5}).then(function(result) {
        //Do something with result
        console.log(result);
    }).catch(function(err) {
        //Error
    });
});
```

I'm running against node.js 4.2.4. I've been experimenting with Bluebird promises but am unsure if that would be useful in this case as I don't fully understand promises (yet).

Comment: You are making all 3000 requests at once so it may just be that whatever machine/service you're requesting to is busy processing all those requests or it could be that the sfs service can't handle 3000 requests and hangs.

Comment: @slebetman thanks. How would you approach slowing that down and making the requests in small batches? I've tried some different libraries which claim to do this but also didn't resolve the problem.

Comment: @codecowboy, actually, you mixed sync. loop, with promises, that's  why you have glitches.

Comment: @NazarSakharenko thanks. Please can you elaborate on this in your answer?

Comment: There is a good topic about Promises, http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/. In your case,for loop, you perform new 'sfs.isSpammer' call on each iteration, without waiting for call result. So, in one moment some of 'sfs.isSpammer' promises became resolved (in same moment of time), and caused thread blocking.

Comment: Can you try setting 'concurrency' to 1? Check if that could resolve your issue. If yes then concurrency is the problem in your application. Try taking different measures to resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use (bluebird) Promise.map to iterate async.

```
connection.query(firstPostQuery, {x: whiteListString}, function(err, rows) {

    Promise.map(rows, function(result, index) {
        console.log('item', index);
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            sfs.isSpammer({
                ip: result.ip,
                email: result.email,
                username: result.poster
            }).then(function(res) {
                console.log('In Promise', res);
                console.log(parseInt(res.username.appears) == 1); //evaluates to
                                                                  // true
                if (res && parseInt(res.username.appears) == 1) {
                    return fs.appendFile(__dirname + '/stopforumspam.txt', res.poster + '\n',
                            function(err) {
                                console.log('In AppendFile spamer');
                                if (err) {
                                    reject(err);
                                }
                                resolve(true);
                            });
                } else {
                    return fs.appendFile(__dirname + '/stopforumspam.txt',
                            'nope\n',
                            function(err) {
                                console.log('In AppendFile good user');
                                if (err) {
                                    reject(err);
                                }
                                resolve(true);
                            });
                }
            });
        });
    }).then(function(res) {
        console.log(res);
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks. I've added some updated code to my question. However, the code after ```if(parseInt(res.username.appears) == 1)``` is not running i.e nothing is written to my file. Is it possible that this is somehow caused by the architecture of the stopforumspam library? https://github.com/deltreey/stopforumspam

Comment: Nope, everything is ok with library, i just forgot to wrap fs.appendFile (since this is async. function) with Promise, answer updated. Should be ok now, with correct execution order;

Comment: thanks. I think you would need to include browserify for that jsFiddle to work though.

Comment: Is it possible there is also an issue with using appendFile like this? Another issue is that the script does not exit.

Comment: There is no callback in 'connection.query' you should add it, according to what you want to do after function complete.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102720/discussion-between-nazar-sakharenko-and-codecowboy).

Comment: promisifying `fs.appendFile` will reduce a lot of code.